# AWS DynamoDB DAX Node.js Example

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb-dax

Does anyone have a good example using AWS DynamoDB DAX in node.js?
And what needs to be considered? (E.g. VPC, Subnet, Security Group, etc.).

I am getting

Error: NoRouteException: No endpoints available

and partially

Error: ValidationException: One of the required keys was not given a value

Don't get data stored, not in the cache, nor on the DB.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is [the TryDax example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.client.run-application-nodejs.html) in the documentation, which describes how to access data using both DynamoDB and DAX - the DAX client should be a drop in replacement. The second error is most likely just a missing part of the key.

Getting VPCs and subnets set up is a bit more involved - the client machine and the cluster must be in the same VPC (or peered VPCs) and both must be in a security group that allows traffic from the client to the cluster. You also need [IAM policies and roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.client.create-user-policy.html) configured correctly so that DAX can authenticate the client.