# AWS DynamoDB DAX "NoRouteException"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I tried to connect to my DAX cluster from my Node.js app per the steps given in [the example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.client.run-application-nodejs.html). I get the following error while connecting to the client.

```
{
      "time": 1581671435720,
      "code": "NoRouteException",
      "retryable": true,
      "requestId": null,
      "statusCode": -1,
      "_tubeInvalid": false,
      "waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying": false
    }
```

I have roles and access permissions as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48791807/5201592) but still I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that DAX cannot be connected from Local Dev Environment. It gets connected only from VPC.

here's the SO link.

[Using AWS DynamoDB DAX from local development machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768785/using-aws-dynamodb-dax-from-local-development-machine)